# Android MyFirstApp tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Android, and I would like to do the tutorial in:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

For some reason, when I create the project the src folder and res/layout folder are empty, therefore I cannot start the tutorial.

I have already tried reinstalling the adt-bundle and recreate the project, but those folders are always empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a bug with the ADT download at the moment.  Find a copy of the files from elsewhere and download or copy paste them in.

Comment: Do you know any place with an older ADT?